# How custom HTTPHandler works in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2010, development, 2013

I am reading some existing code in a project and there are some custom handlers that validate some data on application pages.

The question is: Does these HTTPHandler get executed for every simple HTTP Request on the entire sharepoint farm? or just for a single web app?

The code validates some information from custom field types,

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (GeneralUtilities.ControlQueryString(context))
                {
                    string incomminginformation = context.Request.QueryString[ApplicationResources.QuerystringParameters.ClientCode].ToString();
                    string[] data = null;

                    //When we press the save button and the job is not correct the client will
                    //not be validted beacause its diplayed in an other way.
                    if (incomminginformation.Contains(" - "))
                    {
                        data = incomminginformation.Split('-');
                        string tmp = data[0].Trim();
                        if (tmp.Trim().Length == 8)
                            incomminginformation = tmp;
                    }
```

I also noticed the handlers are somehow called by jquery like this:

```
if (lenght == 8) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "_layouts/15/xx/xx/GenericHandlers/xx.ashx?clientcode=" + currentvalue,
            type: "POST",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler fires when called - sorry, I misread your question. I mentally replaced HTTPHandler with IIS Module.

Old: The httphandlers are registered in the web.config of a Web Application. If only registered in one Web Application it fires only for that one.

Comment: so, this code will be executed for every single request on that web application?

Comment: please check my edit, I noticed there is some jquery that references or uses the ashx files, I guess the handlers will only be used when that jquery code is called, not for all htpp requests in the web application?